# Romex in Commercial Cabinets

Tags: electrical

I am adding some receptacles to the base of an island countertop in an office building.  The island is not attached to the building or floor.   Will be using MC cable up to the the base then a junction box with a short run of romex to the plastic receptacle boxes that are flush mounted.  The romex will be completely concealed behind access panels built into the base and not subject to any damage or exposure to any elements.  Is romex ok for this purpose?

Comment: In commercial work, a couple things. First you need to follow the commercial rules, which are generally all metal boxes, metal conduit and metal jacketed cable... and second in most cases you need to be a licensed electrician.  If you're going to break the second rule, don't break the first.

Comment: It is perfectly OK in terms of normal usage. However, it is quite possible that local *commercial building* electrical code might not allow use of NM. That is jurisdiction dependent.

Comment: Romex is not allowed unless in conduit, so do what a pro would and will meet code use MC. Metal clad would be acceptable in this case.

Comment: Are you a licensed electrician or do you have the relevant qualifications recognized to work in this commercial premises? And any insurance cover?

Comment: What construction type is used for the building, and who's your AHJ?

Comment: @EdBeal  I think this is a gray area since the island is on wheels and not part of the building.  Since it's plugged into a receptacle, doesn't it become an "appliance" at that time?  Just curious.  But if it were me doing this, for the small difference in cost, I'd go with armored cable and metal boxes.

Comment: Thanks @edbeal.    It's not on wheels but more like a countertop base but placed in the middle of the room.  I wouldn't even consider looking for a code related exception if they would have built the base to accept metal junction boxes but I think I'll just have to attempt to do some carpentry to make it work with them.  Ultimately I would always just prefer to use metal; the cost in this instance doesn't effect me.

Comment: Just read what nm is allowed to be used in and commercial and industrial are not there you cannot use Romex (nm) over 3 stories above grade it is the NEC not some local thing.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "in an office building" isn't _Home_ Improvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as general safety, reliability, etc. this would be OK *in a different environment* - i.e., in a single-family home in an area that allows NM cable.

However, code is sometimes about more than that, or rather about *higher* levels of safety in different types of buildings. In particular, code in most commercial buildings (may vary by area and by size of building, but "office building" would typically be such a situation) and in multi-tenant residential buildings (and often one becomes the other over the course of its existence) usually requires metal conduit/metal-clad cable and metal junction boxes for improved safety. Metal simply protects against fire better than plastic, and the more lives and property that are at stake, the more likely that becomes a code requirement.

Replacing the plastic boxes with metal boxes and using metal cable inside the island is likely not a big deal. However, there is an additional important factor - movement. With an island that is permanently attached, permanent wiring via cables to a junction box makes sense. But with a movable island that is a potential disaster. Every time the island is moved - e.g., to mop the floor or to make it easier to use for a demonstration - the metal cable going from the floor to the junction box moves around. Those cables are generally *not* designed for frequent movement (NM isn't either), which will eventually cause problems.

There is an alternative: Install a [floor receptacle](https://amzn.to/3qHxAhr):

[image: Leviton GFCI Floor Receptacle]

and use plug/cord to connect from the island to the receptacle. In a commercial building this:

- Must be installed by a licensed electrician
- Must be UL (or equivalent) listed. The example I included here is a reputable brand, Leviton, but beware of similar-looking junk. Easiest is to have the electrician provide it or tell you exactly what to order.
- Almost certainly needs to be GFCI protected. Even if that is not a strict local code requirement, I would highly recommend it for any floor receptacle in any building, simply to prevent spills or mopping-without-closing-the-cover from resulting in a shocking experience.

That likely avoids any strict "metal only" requirements because this is now a plug-in appliance and not part of the building electrical infrastructure. Plus when you need to move it, you are either moving just a little bit and the cord can handle that, or you unplug it and move it as far as you need to - even out of the room.

That being said, I'd definitely recommend metal boxes for the junction boxes in the island for the plug/cord and for the receptacles. As far as metal cable between them, it *may* be worth it simply to minimize problems later on if you ever get challenged about safety. But properly installed NM inside a cabinet is perfectly safe, and quite common in residential installations.

Based on OP's comment that while this island won't be permanently installed, it will not be easily movable (no wheels), it would definitely be a good idea to use metal cable throughout, as this is *almost* permanently attached. And if you do hard-wire it instead of plug/receptacle, then definitely metal cable.

Comment: Downvoter care to suggest an improvement or tell me where I messed up?

Comment: Thank you very much.  The island is very large and not on wheels, will never actually move.  However, your other points lead me to think it's best to stay exclusively with the MC cable.  They pre-fabbed the electrical box holes on the base for standard plastic boxes so I'll just have to do a bit of carpentry to make it work with  metal boxes.  I don't want any finger pointing at this job if there is a fire or accident down the line.  thanks

Comment: Down vote for “the perfectly fine”. It is not allowed in a commercial environment please do not encourage code violations through ignorance read up on 334.10 on top of that the one and 2 family ,,, so when it goes to a triplex , it can be used inside a raceway this is conduit or a gutter. Above 3 is also a no go. The answer needs to be clear I do not believe this is, especially after all the comments

Comment: I'll edit. I didn't mean "fine" in terms of code. I meant fine in terms of "in a different environment this would be perfectly acceptable as it is a way things".